# Can't login to Django /admin interface

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

First of all, I am a newbie. I'm running **Ubuntu 11.04** which comes with **Python 2.7 so I installed Python2.5** in different dir to run **Django-Non-Rel on Google App Engine**.
I did the Guestbook tutorial and now I am trying to add admin access but when I type in correct username:password Django thinks its incorrect. **It doesn't even work when deployed to GAE.** If you know please poke me in the right direction.

I added:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ( 
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', 
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ....
)
```

EDIT
I also added

> url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

to urls.py in subproject directory.
EOEDIT

Then I created superuser and synced databases:

```
> python2.5 xxx-xxx-guestbook/manage.py createsuperuser python2.5
> xxx-xxx-guestbook/manage.py syncdb
```

Then ran the app and can't login. I created multiple different supersusers always with the same result.

EDIT2

Thanks everyone for trying to help but unfortunately neither of the offered solutions fixed the problem. I have decided to first learn Django on its own and then maybe switch to GAE Django-nonrel, so the question is not relevant anymore. Should I still pick one answer to give someone some points?

Comment: i had the same problem and i believe that BoGs' answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not too sure on this, but syncdb might remove the superuser you just created. Try creating a superuser when syncdb prompts you to.

Otherwise, take a look at the [user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) in `./manage.py shell`. Check `User.objects.all()[0].is_superuser`.

Answer (score 26):

There is some kind of limitation in django-nonrel.

To create a superuser:

- Stop the local webserver
- Create the superuser

  ```
  python manage.py createsuperuser
  ```
- Run the webserver again

  ```
  python manage.py runserver
  ```

Comment: That's what I did yet it still won't let me log in to admin interface.

Comment: worked like a charm. Didn't even have to stop/start webserver. :-)

Comment: Thanks for this, i'm using Django Oscar and their documentation misses this part and doesn't even mentions logging in at all, so thank you

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you have the correct username and password, the only thing that will present the same behavior as a failed login is having `is_staff=False` for the user in question.

Go into your database and inspect the auth_user table. Make sure that `is_staff` is set to `TRUE` on the user you are using to log in.

Comment: This seems to be required if using a custom user model

Answer (score 5):

In urls.py uncomment:

```
# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
**# url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),**
```

and that should make you good for the races :)

PS. do not forget to run a ./manage.py syncdb and it will ask to setup an admin user.

Comment: Thanks but I did that already, just forgot to mention it. I couldn't uncomment it because it wasnt there, so I just added it inurls.py in subproject directory.

Answer (score 5):

If you're an idiot, like me, you might be trying to login with your email rather than your username.

I think I was doing this because when creating the superuser I remembered entering an email and not a username (because django offers you a username without having to type it), and perhaps the usual convention of using emails for usernames.. Man I feel stupid haha.

Comment: Well Django does not ask for a username when creating super user and asks for email when logging in to admin?

Answer (score 5):

I had met the same situation just as you. And I found I switched the authentication backend to

> someproject.backends.EmailCheckmodelBackend

And in the *settings.py* I had added a line:

> AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('someproject.backends.EmailCheckModelBackend',)

And the backend is like:

```
class EmailCheckModelBackend(ModelBackend):
def authenticate(self, username = None, password = None, is_staff = None):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email = username)
        if user.check_password(password):
            if is_staff is not None:
                if user.is_staff == is_staff:
                    return user
                else:
                    return None
            return user

    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

You will find actually the username is forced to be alternated by 'email'. So you have to login your page with email account.
If like

> Username: someone@somewhere.com
>
> password: password

Then it works.
Hope this helpful for everyone.

Comment: Thanks exactly this was the issue I was facing while using DRF. 
I had updated the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` in settings.py to use DRF auth backends. 
I solved the issue by adding this to the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` list => `'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'`

Comment: @SameerKumar You are welcome. That's the question I answered 5 years ago and it still works. LOL

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could not understand why I could not login because all the settings were correct.  However, I traced it to Django offering me a superuser name containing an initial capital letter, but actually saving the name as completely lowercase!

I naturally used the superuser name with capitals (as offered by Django) and authentication failed. When inspecting the data tables to check 'is_staff' etc I spotted the error. I know I was not mistaken because I repeated the setup process a couple of times and noted the superuser credentials to be sure of details like case.

So, the moral is be careful when accepting the default name offered by Django! It lies!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I setup a Redis server

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It's not that difficult to fix.
First of all make sure to allow your default settings

```
(DEBUG=TRUE,ALLOWED_HOST=[ ])
```

in the settings file of your website folder.

Get into your website folder (using the command prompt), and type the following command:

```
$ python manage.py createsuperuser
name:
email:e.g fulluser@admin.com
password:
```

Go back into the browser and run the server. Set the username (not the email), alongside your password which you created earlier. It will surely work fine this time.