# Unable to log into the Django admin

Tags: django, authentication

Im trying to log into the admin GUI but keep getting the error :

*Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields are case-sensitive.*

Ive created a new user, dropped all the db tables for auth_xxx and resynced. And also checked that the is_staff,is_active,is_superuser flags are all true within the db.

Does anyone have any other ideas ?

Comment: Have you looked at and followed the directions in the second answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751434/cant-login-to-django-admin-interface ?

Comment: did you sync after creating a  new user? You can always create another user from the shell prompt - `./manage.py createsuperuser`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following within the settings.py resolved the issue

```
django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend
```